# CSS Absolute position in Chrome with Media queries

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, media-queries

I'm currently trying to display a selection of divs in a single row. When the user is on a small screen device, I split the row into multiple fragments.

The problem I'm currently facing is if the user starts in a small window, and then expands the window the rows won't merge together. I believe this is because the toggle is already positioned and chrome doesn't re-calculate absolute positions when the screen changes size. I tested this same page in IE 11, and the rows end up merging.

So my question: How do I get the CSS to recalculate the absolute position upon screen size change? I'd prefer to avoid using JS if possible.

Scenarios:

1 Big to small, back to big.

- User starts the window larger than 35em. There should be only a single row
- User resizes the window to smaller then 35em. There should now be multiple rows
- User resizes the window back to something larger than 35em. There should be only a single row left.

2 Small to big

- User loads the window smaller than 35em. There should be multiple rows.
- User resizes the window to larger than 35em. There should be only a single row. This is where it fails. I believe that in chrome since the checkbox is positioned absolutely the div only moves as far back as the checkbox allows.

  ```
  .toggle {
      /* This is where the problem occurs I believe.  */
      position: absolute;
      /* We use left so that the user will still be on the same level*/
      left: -9999px;
  }

  .toggle + div label {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: blue;
      color: #FFF;
      border: 2px solid #FFF;
  }

  /* Small Screen */
  @media (max-width: 35em) {
      .toggle + div {
          display: block;
      }

      .toggle + div label {
          display: block;
      }

  }
  /* Large Screen */
  @media (min-width: 35em) {
      .toggle + div {
          display: inline-block;
      }

      .toggle + div label {
          display: inline-block;
      }

  }
  ```

```html
    <main>
        <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" >
        <div>
            <label>Test1</label>
        </div>

        <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" >
        <div>
            <label>Test2</label>
        </div>

        <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" >
        <div>
            <label>Test3</label>
        </div>

    </main>
```

Edited:
  JSFiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/wgLwkd85/

Comment: `left: -9999px;` ... well ?

Comment: I'm sorry what are you asking?

Comment: It's very unusual to use such left value. On the other hand, try to make a JSFiddle.

Comment: The reason why I had toggle as -9999px is because I want the user to still be able to select it through the keyboard. Originally I had it set as display: none, but for accessibility issues I was forced to do left: -9999px. The reason why I don't add a top value to this is that when the user does tab through the options the window should not go scroll all the way back to the very top. I have made a JSFiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/wgLwkd85/), but you will only see the changes when you run the program with the window small and then expand.

Comment: Rather than using 'left' to position the checkbox off the screen, you can add a tabindex attribute to the label to make it keyboard-accessible.  That said, the statement "in chrome since the checkbox is positioned absolutely the div only moves as far back as the checkbox allows" is not correct - absolutely positioned elements do not affect the placement of other elements (other than their own descendants).

Comment: @phari I have no been able to add tabindex attribute to label, and if the absolutely positioned elements do not affect the placement of other elements, how come the divs don't form a row in chrome?

Comment: The divs are forming a row when I view this code in Chrome using your "large screen" CSS (although not in JSFiddle, not sure why).  When the "small screen" CSS activates, the divs form a column because they have display:block.  If you leave them with display:inline-block, the row of divs wraps if the screen is not wide enough - if this is not the behavior you want, please clarify what you want it to do instead.

Comment: @phari This bug only occurs in Chrome and  only when you start the page in small and expand to large. This is covered in the second scenario I outlined in my post. And yes I know they will form a column because of display: block; This was intended, the thing is that they don't form a row when you start the page in a small view port and expand.